# Git uncommitted changes doesn't show after copying to a different computer

Tags: git

Ok so i have a rails application and i made changes to it on one computer and didn't commit the changes to the git repo and then i zipped the whole folder and copied it to a new computer to continue working later but what weirdly happened was when i started my rails application it  works as it should after the changes i made on the previous computer but when i open the code it still shows the code that was there at the previous commit in other words the changes that are showing up in the localhost server isn't anywhere to be found in the files i tried even deleting the entire code and it had no effect on the page after refresh and even after i restarted the server. I came to the conclusion that it must be getting the code from some temp library but showing me the code as it were in the last commit but the question now is how do i access these files without having to go back the other computer and committing the changes and then re-copy/re-zip to the other computer ?? i've been using git for all of 4 months really i don't know if this is a completely new problem or just something weird with my app. Any suggestions would be appreciated. My version of rails is 3.2.13

Thanks!!

Comment: Please format your question into smaller paragraphs, because right now it's just a giant, unreadable wall of text. Also pay attention to how you capitalize your "I"s please (don't use "i").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not committed the changes to your GIT repository, but saved the changes locally - those changes will be reflected on that particular machine only. For you to be able to access the modified code, you would have to PULL the last Committed code i.e, from the GIT Repository. Since you have not Committed to the Git Repository. I suggest you with the following (2) options.

1. Commit the changes to your GIT Repository from the previous machine and PULL the code to your new machine.
2. Copy the zip folder (The one with the updated code) from your previous machine to your present machine, commit from the new machine and PULL a fresh copy of code from your new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turned out that on the new computer i hadn't installed the git gem yet once i did everything started working fine!